# Return list in form of string with the seperator

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def buggy_join(input, sep=","):
    list=input
    print list
    str="".join(str(x) for x in list)
    print str
    str=sep.join(str)
    return str
buggy_join(range(6))
```

This is my code where I should get the result as `"0,1,2,3,4,5"`. Where is the mistake in my code. Please tell.

Comment: What is the error message and/or incorrect output that you get?

Comment: @interjay: the funny thing is that the code would work weren't it for the double use of `str`. Until, that is, you use ranges that produce integers over 9....

Answer (score 3):

You joined the list with the empty string separator, then joined the resulting string with comma.

Just join the list with the comma to begin with:

```
def working_join(input, sep=","):
    result = sep.join([str(v) for v in input])
    return result
```

Using `str.join()` with a string input puts the separator between all the individual characters:

```
>>> ','.join('Hello world!')
'H,e,l,l,o, ,w,o,r,l,d,!'
```

That's because a string is a sequence too. That's fine for ranges counting up to `9`, but for `10` and up you'd put a comma between the `1` and `0` characters.

Try not to use names like `str` and `list`; those are built-in types and by using them for other objects in your own code, you end up masking the built-in types and cannot use them when you need them. In that vein, `input` is also a built-in function, but it is less likely you'll need it in this function.

Because you tried to use `str` as both the built-in type (to convert individual elements in `input` to strings) *and* as a local name, your function throws a `NameError`; Python marked `str` as a local in your function, not the built-in object. This then leads to `str` in the generator expression referencing the `str` variable in the function, and the whole thing breaking down as that name hasn't been assigned anything yet.

Comment: It's working in the visualizer but doesn't work on the console.It says: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable". What does this mean?

Comment: @NavyaVaishnavi: you assigned a string to whatever you tried to call. For example `str = 'some string'` then `str(1)` won't work, because `str` is no longer bound to a function.